# How to add a checklist in Google Docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

How can one add a checklist in Google Docs using JavaScript. I'm inserting multiple keywords that I want to apply checklist as bullet points where users can click and unclick.

Comment: I could not find any way to create checklists with google apps script.  I think there pretty new so may be it will be coming soon.  Or perhaps someone else will know more about it.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it doesn't look like it's possible right now, but there is a workaround.

When you [`getType()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element#gettype) a checklist `Element`, you do get the ['ListItem`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/list-item) type.

Logically this means that the check box should be a [`GlyphType`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/glyph-type), but there is no documented type that corresponds to a checklist. If you try to execute [`getGlyphType()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/list-item#getglyphtype) on a manually created check list, you get `null`. And, of course, if you try to [`setGlyphType(null)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/list-item#setglyphtypeglyphtype), you don't get a check box.

So through reading documentation and some tests we have to conclude that it's not currently possible, unfortunately.

However, you can create a detached copy of a checklist with a `copy()` method along the lines of:

```js
body.appendListItem(listItem.copy()));
```

The checklist can be in a different document of course. I did not find a way to manipulate the check list text values (it seems to override everything), so you might want to pre-define list items in a separate document beforehand.

Comment: Thank you, for the quick response. I will try that.

I have been using String.fromCharCode(9745) 9745 will insert checked bullet points and String.fromCharCode(9744) will insert blank square bullet points. So I'm wondering if I can find the code to insert the checklist!

Comment: You can't. Don't confuse JavaScript with Google Apps Script :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it like this in Python thru the Google Docs API:

```
# open the doc
doc = service.documents().get(documentId=docId).execute()

# iterate thru the content sections finding the highest endIndex value,
# afterwhich I will add my checklist
content = doc['body']['content']
nextIndex = max([v['endIndex'] for v in content]) + 1

# create a set of batchUpdate requests to insert each line of my checklist array of strings
requests = []
for line in checklist:
    requests.append({
        'insertText': {
            'text': line + '\n',
            'endOfSegmentLocation': {}     # using this will add lines to end of doc
        }
    })

# add the clecklist text lines 
service.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=docId, body={'requests': requests}).execute()

# get the updated doc
doc = service.documents().get(documentId=docId).execute()

# find the new 'endIndex' value
content = doc['body']['content']
lastIndex = max([v['endIndex'] for v in content])

# create a request to set the range of my checklist to a BULLET_CHECKBOX list
requests = [
    {
        'createParagraphBullets': {
            'range': {
                'startIndex': nextIndex,
                'endIndex': lastIndex
            },
            'bulletPreset': 'BULLET_CHECKBOX'
        },
    }
]
service.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=docId, body={'requests': requests}).execute()
```