# How to autoformat a dynamic checklist in google docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a large checklist that changes each week in google sheets, and I have automated those changes, but once I get to the stage of using the checklist I have 2 options: (1) Print it out and scratch off each item, or (if I forget to print it) (2) Have each item preceded by a tickbox that I can click on my phone which will strike it out.

Currently, the easiest way to do (2) seems to be in google docs with the checklist button.  I have linked the spreadsheet checklist to the doc so the doc will automatically update whenever the checklist in sheets updates.  The only part I have left to automate is reformatting the linked table in docs to do 2 things:

- Add a checkbox to each line in each cell in the linked table that: (1) Falls into a certain range (the third-twelfth rows and third-sixth columns, or in sheets language C3-F12), and (2) is not blank
- Decrease the auto indent for the list items (both the checkbox and text) by 75%

Is there any way to automate this inside google docs using a menu button?  It's the sort of thing I would use a macro for in sheets, but docs doesn't seem to have a parallel for some reason.

I don't believe a solution inside google sheets will work because I currently have multiple checklist items stored inside a single cell, and in sheets the only checklist workaround would involve having a single checkbox strikethrough every single line in that cell instead of having a separate checkbox per list item.

I would greatly appreciate any help!

I know how to do this manually in docs, but am just looking for an automation.  I don't know any code and so can't generate a solution in docs.

I haven't found anything quite like it in Stack Overflow, though I did see a post titled [How to add a checklist in Google Docs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69950693/1330560) from 1 year ago mentioning AppScript couldn't turn something into a checklist type at that point, but Python could.

On why this wouldn't work in sheets, see the Stack Overflow question titled [Single cell checklist in google sheets.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73314295/1330560)

Comment: The "accepted" answer in [How to add a checklist in Google Docs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69954394/1330560) is not a python-specific solution; as the user notes, it is a workaround.

Comment: One of the most recent Q&A on this topic is [Using Apps Script, how can I display a google doc checklist from information in a google sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76494279/1330560). It is perhaps not exactly what you were looking for but it does represent another solution. As noted elsewhere, the disadvantage of a script in Google Docs is that it has no onEdit(e) (trigger) like there is in Google Spreadsheet, so if someone checks a box nothing will happen unless you install a custom menu item and that is triggered."

Comment: This can be easily done on a mobile with a simple onEdit().  It works on desktop and mobile with no problems.`function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 0 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart)
  }
}
`

Comment: It would be easier for me to do it in html than google docs.

Comment: Why would you want more than one checkbox in a single cell?